# ng-repeat overwriting values cause key fields provided by Breeze (from EF) are identical

Tags: breeze, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a legacy database where the keys may be identical between rows. Other data that should be shown by the repeater is not identical. The database is EF-mapped (the key fields are marked as keys there) and Breeze is used to deliver the data from EF to Angluar. It seems that the rows shown by the repeater are overwritten by data from latter rows with identical keys.

This is what kind of Json Breeze retrieves from the api:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$type": "Breeze.WebApi2.QueryResult, Breeze.WebApi2",
  "Results": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "_I...lade",
      "Key1": "11",
      "Key2": "22",
      "text1": 1.0,
      "text2": "00000000032800134220",
      "text3": 15.00
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "$type": "_I...lade",
      "Key1": "11",
      "Key2": "22",
      "text1": 2.0,
      "text2": "00000000044800102213",
      "text3": 5.00
    },
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "$type": "_I...lade",
      "Key1": "11",
      "Key2": "22",
      "text1": 12.0,
      "text2": "000000000512002321",
      "text3": 33.00
    }
  ],
  "InlineCount": 3
}
```

I try to show the data from the text* -fields but it seems that Angular (or Breeze) realizes that the key* -fields have identical values and then on every row ng-repeat shows the values of the third (last) resultset.

Still the $index prints fine on every row

```
ng-repeat="a in vm.data track by $index"
```

I tried to use the ng-repeat also this way to utilize the Breeze's $id attribute seen above:

```
ng-repeat="a in vm.data track by $id($id)"
```

Or
    ng-repeat="a in vm.data track by $id(a.$id)"

But then Angular gives the dupes error:

> [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track
>   by' expression to specify unique keys.

Also everything starts to work fine if I tell EF that all the fields it provieds for Breeze are keys. I presume this works only cause so far not all the fields have been identical.

Is there a possibility to make this work at the front end either by Breeze or Angular? Maybe by using the Breeze provided $id, which is unique on every row?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your legacy database is and how it accommodates records with non-unique keys. In EF you can't designate some property (or property combination) as the key  unless it is unique. In Breeze, every entity must have a unique primary key.

That said, Breeze is happy to return data from the server that are not keyed. These data aren't entities and they aren't cached. But they are returned from the query. A projection query is a typical example.

Breeze is irrelevant here. Angular's `ng-repeat` is giving you the error because (I think) you are iterating with a primitive JavaScript value [as explained here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

I would have thought that `ng-repeat="a in vm.data track by $index"` would get you out of the jam. It doesn't? How can that be? You'd have to show me the actual failing ngRepeat (and the values of `vm.data`) for me to believe it.

Finally, there is no `$id` in the data returned by Breeze. The `$id` you see on the wire is a serialization artifact that disappears by the time the JSON is returned to you by Breeze. Your attempt to track by it (or any derivative of it) fails with an ng-dupes error because the value of `anything.$id` is always the same: `undefined`.

Comment: the EF entity where there were identical keys was a union defining query which had the same rows as keys. This situation caused the ngRepeat overwriting non-key fields of rows that had the same keys even with track by $index. This is now handled by having a type field in the union defining query and marking that as a key along the old ones. Now ngRepeat has separate key values and seems to work fine. Thanks for the answer, it cleared som aspects for me anyway :)